# Perform aggregation to eliminate duplicates and get unique counts

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongo `documents` like below, want to perform aggregation to find the errorcodes count for each unique contacts.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": ""
  }, 
  "campId": "61baef7817cd8ff66518", //camp1
  "contactId": "61aa6fbf77490b0007714273", // contact 1
  "title": "Happy Holidays!",
  "communicationType": "EMAIL", 
  "contactedOnTime": {
    "$numberLong": "1695182032" // AT TIME1
  },  
  "communicationValidationError": "EMAIL_ADDRESS_NOT_PRESENT"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": ""
    },
    "campId": "61baef7817cd8ff66518", //camp1
    "contactId": "61aa6fbf77490b0007714273", // contact1
    "title": "Happy Holidays!",
    "communicationType": "EMAIL",  
    "contactedOnTime": {
        "$numberLong": "1695182074" // AT TIME2 
    },
    "communicationValidationError": "EMAIL_ADDRESS_NOT_PRESENT"
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": ""
    },
    "campId": "61baef7817cd8ff66518", // camp1
    "contactId": "61aa6fbf77490b0007714274", // contact2
    "title": "Happy Holidays!",
    "communicationType": "EMAIL",
    "contactedOnTime": {
        "$numberLong": "1695182059" 
    },
    "communicationValidationError": "EMAIL_BOUNCED"
}
```

I have tried below, however this doesn't eliminate the duplicate contacts for a camp and shows count as 2 instead of 1. I need to pick latest communicationValidationError for unique contacts and get it as `totalcounts` of communicationValidationError of a campId.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { $project: { _id: 0, campId: 1, contactId: 1, communicationValidationError: 1 } },
    { $sort: { "contactedOnTime.numberLong":-1}},
    { $match: { campId: '61baef7817cd8ff66518' } },
    { $group: { _id: { communicationValidationError: '$communicationValidationError' }, totalErrors: { $sum: 1 } } }
]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main point:

> **Pick latest `communicationValidationError` for unique contacts and get it as `totalcounts` of `communicationValidationError` of a campId.**

Thus, the query should be:

1. `$match`
2. `$setWindowFields` - Add new field `rankInLatest`. This will group the documents by `contactId` with the ranking by `contactedOnTime` descending.
3. `$match` - Filter the document with `rankInLatest: 1`. This will return each document of `contactId` with the latest `contactedOnTime`.
4. `$group` - Group by `communicationValidationError` and perform the count.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      campId: "61baef7817cd8ff66518"
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$contactId",
      sortBy: {
        contactedOnTime: -1
      },
      output: {
        rankInLatest: {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      rankInLatest: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        communicationValidationError: "$communicationValidationError"
      },
      totalErrors: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/90NqilYUYh7)

Comment: but this will not return unique sets. single campId has multiple contacts in it (these contacts might be duplicates as well) and each contact has error;

Comment: Ok noted. Misunderstood. You should group by `communicationValidationError`, `campId` and `contactId` too. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JBBOp_Nzwrq)

Comment: If the `contactId` is associate to single `campId`, then group by `communicationValidationError` and `contactId` should be enough.

Comment: I tried executing demo link you shared, that narrows down to the solution partially. Say if a campId has 2 documents with same contact at time1 and time2, then the current solution is considering both where as it must consider only the time2 which is latest. i tried playing around by sorting time field and then grouping by that, that doesn't work.  [Demo] (https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Yii1XQLXVe)

Comment: yes, i have added one more document to the data list, [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Yii1XQLXVe) , with this `EMAIL_BOUNCED` should be 0

Comment: Revised answer. This should be what you need. Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Though the above answer by @Yong Shun worked, i had to achieve same without using `$setWindowFields:` as i wasn't able to frame it in java `spring-boot`. Here is [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/SetWindowFieldsOperation.html) showing that the spring supports this operation, however i wasn't able to! Maybe the `spring-version` i was using not supporting this.

So, i tried to re-write the query using `group` stages. I have put it below for somebody who is facing same issue as mine,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      contactedOnTime: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      campId: "61baef7817cd8ff66518"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        contactId: "$contactId"
      },
      doc: {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "_id"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$errorCode",
      totalErrors: {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```